# What does the "opening at the hull side of their bench" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

This context comes from the book "Black Rednecks And white liberals" by Thomas Sowell

"When the ship was idle, slaves who needed to relieve themselves could
make their way to **the opening at the hull side of their bench**, known as the borda, dragging their part of the chain and presumably climbing
over their sleeping companions"

The sentence in bold type seems to me as if there is a bench, in which there are two sides, one the hull side, and the other, not specified, and that there is an opening, at the **hull side of** that bench. Does it mean that **the bench is perpendicular to the hull** and the hole is inside **the top of the bench** (just like a primitive toilet without the toilet seat) where a person's buttocks are when that person sits, by the side of the ship where the oar is sticking out? (or on the other side for that matter).

Comment: What is the context/source?

Comment: Presumably we're talking galley slaves here. They would sit on benches perpendicular to the ship's side; the writer means 'the end of the bench nearest to the hull'. I suspect that the 'opening' is simply the hole in the ship's side which the oar passes through.

Comment: @Kate Bunting What I really wanna know is the meaning of the preposition "of". If I replace "the hull side of their bench" with "the left side of their bench" the preposition "of" suggests to me that "the side" referred to is that of "the bench" not of  " the ship". It would be the other way round if the sentence was "the left side from the bench". Am I correct?

Comment: @alphabet I added the source material to the post.

Comment: "Borda" is the Spanish word for "gunwale":  The top edge of the hull of a nautical vessel, where it meets the deck. So, I would assume this opening is in the hull, at the location of the gunwale, presumably just under the deck, possibly even the gap that the oars protrude from, not a hole in the bench. So, they were defalcating directly  into the sea, over the side of the ship.

Comment: @Billy Kerr Can we know for certain, based **solely** on the sentence "the opening at the hull side of their bench" that the opening is either at the hull or their bench?

Comment: If it's important to you, perhaps do some research on the construction of the vessels used by these pirates at that time.  I'm only making an assumption here based on my limited knowledge. I'm no expert in the field.  The wording is a little awkward though. I will give you that.

Comment: This is the English-language forum dude. I am discussing the language usage and not the construction of ships. "The wording is a little awkward though" is suitable to it, but I came here to find out **"why is it awkward according to a native speaker"** so I can understand the language more deeply.

Comment: The only thing I find awkward is that he refers to the _side_ of the bench rather than the _end_. The opening is adjacent to the end of the bench which is nearest to the hull (not the end in the middle of the vessel, assuming there are two rows of benches).

Comment: What was confusing to me was the usage of the preposition "of" and I wanted to know the difference between "at the hull side **of** their bench" vs "at the hull side **from** their bench".

Comment: _At the side from_ isn't idiomatic English.

Comment: "At the left side from" their bench isn't idiomatic either, even though correct. What's the difference?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'correct'. _At the [left] side from..._ is not how we say it in English.

Comment: Why can you say "at the hull side of their bench" and not "at the left side of their bench"? The words "hull" and "left" both specify which **"side of the bench"** the sentence is referring to. Am I right?

Comment: I said that 'at the left side **from**' was unidiomatic!

Comment: Is "unidiomatic" synonymous with "incorrect"?